# DockerHub Webhook trigger Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, docker, webhooks, dockerhub

I tried to use https://github.com/jenkinsci/dockerhub-plugin but failed.
This project seems to be exactly what I want, but it seems that this project is not being actively developed. The documentation is basically 0. Is there any plan to move forward with this project? Is there any other project that can do same/similar things?

My project currently fails to pull the docker image from DockerHub. I need to install docker on the Jenkins host, right? And also my image on DockerHub is private. How can I pull the image?

So when configure the Jenkins project, I need to enter the "Image ID" for the image that it will pull from DockerHub. However the whole point is that I want Jenkins to do some testing and then tell DockerHub it passed or not and then DockerHub can publish the image or not.
So is it possible to use the content of the WebHook that DockerHub sent to Jenkins to pull the image (which I believe is not published yet)?

Thank you very much!

--Gordon

Comment: I actually want to do the opposite but can't seem to find a way. Upon finishing a build in Jenkins execute a Docker Hub Automated Build Trigger so the image can be built by the Docker Hub itself. Anyone has any suggestions other than write a new plugin or modify the existing one?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better plan is probably to abandon the DockerHub Webhook and build the image in Jenkins. You can then test the image in Jenkins and push to the DockerHub manually if it succeeds.

It's much easier and better supported to use GitHub/Bitbucket hooks and plugins to trigger the build than the DockerHub one (which doesn't seem to have had much activity for a while as you say).